# dplyr error "length(xmin) == 1 is not TRUE" with mutate when using the integral() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with as follows

```
lower <- c(1,5,15)
upper <-c(5,15,30)
df<-data.frame(lower,upper)
```

I would like to use dplyr's mutate to create a new variable of the area under the curve of a defined function. The function is as follows.

```
my_fun <- function(x){y = 1.205016 + 0.03796243 * log(x)}
```

I am using the `integral()`  function from the `pracma`  package to find the area under the curve. When I use this function on an a pair of upper and lower values it runs with no Errors as follows.

```
integral(my_fun, 1,5)
[1] 4.973705`
```

However, when I try to run this same function using dplyr's mutate, I get the following.

```
new_df <- df %>%
   mutate(new_variable = integral(my_fun, lower, upper))
```

> Error in integral(my_fun, lower, upper) : length(xmin) == 1 is not
> TRUE

It seems that the `integral` function must be reading the whole vectors `df$lower` and `df$upper`rather than the individual pairs of values `1,5`. Is there a solution to this using dplyr's `mutate`, or should I be looking for other solutions.

I did some looking around and the only instances of this error related to mutate did not seem to address the issue I have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(pracma)
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
     mutate(new_variable = integral(my_fun, lower, upper))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
#  lower upper new_variable
#  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#1     1     5         4.97
#2     5    15        12.9 
#3    15    30        19.8
```

---

Or with `map2`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
     mutate(new_variable = map2_dbl(lower, upper, ~integral(my_fun, .x, .y)))
```

-output

```
#  lower upper new_variable
#1     1     5     4.973705
#2     5    15    12.907107
#3    15    30    19.837273
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
df %>%
     mutate(new_variable = pmap_dbl(cur_data(), ~ integral(my_fun, ..1, ..2)))
#  lower upper new_variable
#1     1     5     4.973705
#2     5    15    12.907107
#3    15    30    19.837273
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$new_variable <-  unlist(Map(function(x, y) 
          integral(my_fun, x, y), df$lower, df$upper))
```

---

Or using `apply` from `base R`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) integral(my_fun, x[1], x[2]))
#[1]  4.973705 12.907107 19.837273
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you know of a resource that would help me understand why I got this error? I am used to using mutate() with other functions, and have not seen this error before.

Comment: @Rhizoblaster You meant the error on your function or the one based on my code?

Comment: @Rhizoblaster if it is the error showed on your post, it is just that the function is not vectorized for the arguments.  i.e. it can take only single lower, upper value and not multiple values.  So, it stops at the length check when it is greater than 1